# Can't change vue-moment locale

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

So, I'm using vue-moment on my personal project. On this project the user can choose what language he prefers. In the footer, exists a select where the user changes the application language. When he changes, i18n change the language, but, moment doesn't.

Here's the vue-moment config:

```
import moment from 'moment';

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'), {
  moment
});
```

And here's the method:

```
changeLocale({ value, moment }) {
  this.$i18n.locale = value;
  this.$moment.locale(moment)
},
```

Comment: what are `value` and `moment`?

Comment: "value" is for the i18n value for locale, and "moment" is for the moment.js value for locale, because it's different string values (e.g value: "pt_BR", moment: "pt-br")

Comment: I think you need to ensure you have done `import es from '/moment/locale/es'` or similar  - do you have those imports in your vue component?

Comment: @Bassie thank you! worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, please ensure you first import the language you are trying to change to using, for example:

```
import es from '/moment/locale/es'
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is (main.js):

```
const moment = require('moment');
require('moment/locale/uk');
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'), {moment});
```